# LD$t(L)$ factorization and eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

A positive definite matrix $A$ can be factored in to $LDt(L)$form. Is the statement the eigenvalues of $A$ are the diagonals of $D$ true? If so , how to prove it?

Comment: Question: What is $LDt(L)$ form? Is this another notation for $LDL^{T}$?

Answer (score 2):

No, far from true. The product of the diagonals is the determinant of $A$, hence is equal to the product of the eigenvalues. What *is* true ([Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)) is that — for any symmetric matrix $A$ — the signs of the entries of $D$ match up with the signs of the set of eigenvalues, including the number of zeroes (which is, of course, the dimension of $\mathbf N(A) = \ker(A)$).